# Fibaro Wall Plug FGWPE_F-101 Node has failed

Tags: home-automation

I have a Fibaro Wall Plug FGWPE_F-101 that I try to connect to my newly established HA system.
I use The Domoticz software on a Raspberry Pi w/Razberry HW to manage this. The system discovers the plug, and I can add the switch to turn on/off light. But here the problem starts.
Now the plug gets unreachable by Domoticz. I get the Error: OpenZWave: Node has failed (or is not alive), Switch command not sent!
The plug is glowing white, and by the looks of it, it is alive. So what can this be?

I have three plugs, and all seem to have this problem.

I brought the system (RPi and Fibaro plugs) to work today, just to test some more there. But at work I don't get this problem. How can this be? It works great on the powergrid and network at work, but not at home...

Comment: Checking to see if this might be more appropriate for Raspberry Pi, hardware compatibility and software problems tend to be out of scope here, but we haven't done a good job defining that just yet.

Comment: so the exact same hardware setup works at "work" but not at "home"? sounds like network settings.

Comment: Like interference on the frequence used by z-wave? How can I map out problems like this?
Is it possible that Fibaro Wall plugs can be affected by i.e. ground fault at one of my neighbours? I recently had an electrician over to change some switcher, and he noticed a ground fault that came form outside my electrical system.

Comment: "Glowing white" - that doesn't sound like a default setting from reading a manual.  OTOH - I cast an eye over the [Fibaro official Forums](http://forum.fibaro.com/) and I note that they did have some issues with various things with pre- Ver4.0 software - and some device types (Dimmers?) with Safety Approval problems in Sweden and then Norway.  One hopes by now that things have been sorted....